# iPhone Post Image to Web Sever - still working?

Tags: php, iphone, xcode, post, uiimagepickercontroller

I know there have been a lot of questions regarding posting images to a web server and many have been answered. This tutorial: http://zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/ is often referenced.

Can anyone confirm for me that this tutorial code still works with Xcode 4.3? I appear to get a 'Format string is not a string literal' warning on the 'NSLog(returnString);'. Furthermore, the console tells me that /test-upload.php was not found on the server... Is something going wrong or has the upload script simply been removed by the creator of the tutorial?

That said, assuming that it does work, can I just using his code (at the very of the tutorial) for a php script to post to in order to handle copying the file?

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: http://iphone.zcentric.com/test-upload.php is 404 - took 2s to test that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still works because i use it in an app i have on the appstore.  The NSLog is no big deal.  It's just memory managment stuff, it's telling you it could be a possible memory leak.  NSLog's usually like to receive strings like this:

```
    NSLog(@"%@", myNSString);
```

And the php script on his server was missing aswell, don't worry about the error but if you are to put an app on the appstore make sure to get rid of the NSLog code snippets just for good memory management.  You wont get into much trouble if you don't but it could just make an inconvenience.